# Ambiguous Use of 'SubScript' in Swift-2.2, Xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I'm trying a App with CommonCrypto,

so I download a SHA256.swift from [CryptoCoinSwift/SHA256-Swift](https://github.com/CryptoCoinSwift/SHA256-Swift), and add it into my project.

In my unit test, I create a function to test whether the file is good or not ?

Here is my code in unit test :

```
func testCrypto() {
    let a: String = "123456"
    let b = SHA256.hexStringDigest(a)    <- error line
    print(b)
}
```

Error line

```
 Ambiguous use of 'hexStringDigest'
```

Could anyone tell me, what's wrong with my code ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So going through the GitHub project you cited, I found 2 functions named `hexStringDigest`, both accept a string as input:

```
public static func hexStringDigest (input : String) -> NSData
public static func hexStringDigest (input : String) -> String
```

Swift was confused which one you wanted. Give the compiler a hint:

```
let b: String = SHA256.hexStringDigest(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to say either

```
let b : NSData = SHA256.hexStringDigest(a)
```

or

```
let b : String = SHA256.hexStringDigest(a)
```

(depending which one you want).